# How to Get All Indexes of an Element in a Linked List in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a linked list. I want to set a weight factor p^i for each position i of this list. Then I want to get a weighted value for the elements of the list as the sum of these factors.

Let me give an example to make things concrete. Let us say that my list has size 5, i.e. it has elements from index 0 to index 4. Let us say that p = 0.5 (i.e. p = 1/2). Hence, the weighting factor of position 0 is p^0 = 1, of position 1 is p^1 = 0.5, of position 2 is p^2 = 0.25, of position 3 is p^3 = 0.125, and finally of position 4 is p^4 = 0.0625.

Let us now assume that I have the following items in the list, from position 0 to position 4 (I give the IDs of these items): 4 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 5. Therefore, since the item with ID = 4 is in the positions 0, 1, and 3, its value should be the sum of these weighting factors, that is, p^0 + p^1 + p^3 = 1 + 0.5 + 0.125 = 1.625. Similarly, for the item with ID = 5 we have p^2 + p^4 = 0.25 + 0.0625 = 0.3125.

My problem is: How to get ALL the indexes where these elements (ID 4 and ID 5) are located in the list in order to calculate the value of these elements as the sum of the associated with these indexes weighting factors? indexOf(Object o) returns the index of the first occurence of the specified element in the list, I need the index of all occurences. Any suggestion?

**EDIT: Updated to a geometrically decreasing sum instead of increasing**

I did a modification to my code, instead of having a geometrically increasing sum in my list (which i call window and takes objects of type Request) to have a geometrically decreasing sum. My code (which I post it here exactly as it is in my program) works just fine if a I have a small number of requests (e.g. 100 - I set the number of requests at the main method of my Main class - the entrypoint of the code). However, if I use for example 1000 requests, I get an error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
```

which refers to another point in my code where I have:

```
if(reqToBeRemoved == null) {

    reqToBeRemoved = 
minKeyList.get((new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt(minKeyList.size())));

}
```

Here is my code, I hope what I post here to be usefull (obviously I cannot post the whole code here, neither it is required I guess):

```
public void doWindowLookup(Request request) {

    int index = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double initVal = 0;

    for(Request r : window) {

        if(r.equals(request)) {

            if(index == 0) {

                initVal = 1;

            }

            else {

                request.weight = Math.pow(p, index);
                sum += request.weight;

            }

            request.weightedWinFreq = initVal - sum;

        }

        index++;
    }

    logger.info("TEST: Item: " + request.reqID + " has weightedWinFreq: " +
                 request.getWeightedWinFreq());

}
```

What this error message means? Which general item n should be positive??? I assume when I call random.nextInt() I pass a zero argument (as indicated by the previous thread [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072594/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-n-must-be-positiv)), but how is this possible, since my argument is minKeyList.size()?

(If my question needs additional clarification, please ask me to provide the required info.)

**EDIT: Regarding the Previous Update to My Question: It Was My Fault in Another Part of the Program. Question Considered to be Answered.**

Comment: How about iterating and updating a temporary sum. After iterating all elements you'll have the final sum.

Comment: @baraky: I can iterate in order to set the weight factors for each position - and I actually do that: for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { list.get(i).setWeight(Math.pow(p, i)); } where the setter setWeight is public void setWeight(double val) { weight = val; }. My problem is how to find the positions of an element in the list, in order to sum the corresponding weighting factors and get its value.

Comment: @NewJavaStudent Never do a for(i) loop on a LinkedList.  That's an O(N^2) operation:  Use an Iterator, explicitly or implicitly, as shown below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always loop through the list manually:

```
double weight = 0.0;
Object target = new Integer(4);
int index = 1;
for (Object elem : linkedList) {
    if (elem.equals(target)) {
        weight += Math.pow(p, index);
    }
    index++;
}
```

Comment: Why `equals`? I think it should simply be `weight += elem*Math.pow(p,i)`.

Comment: @torquestomp: The code works except from one detail - of course, it may be my fault, how I integrated the code into my program. Anyway, let me explain. I have in my list the items with ID 5 | 2 | 1 | 5. I use as starting value for the index the value zero (0). So for item 5 I should have after the loop a weight 1 + 0.125 = 1.125. However, the code gives me 2.125. Thus, it does the following: takes the value 1 for index 0 at the first time, and then takes again the value 1 for index 0 and the value 0.125 for index 4, and sums all together (I assume).

Comment: Let me put it another way. Initially the list is empty. It is inserted into the list the item 5 at index 0. Its value is 1. Then the item 2 is inserted into the list at index 0 and the item 5 is right-shifted at index 1. Thus, now the item 2 has a value 1 and the item 5 has a value 0.5. And so on. Hence, at the end the item 5 which is located at indexes 0 and 4 will have a value 1 + 0.125 = 1.125, the item 2 located at index 1 will have a value 0.5, and the item 1 located at index 3 will have a value 0.25.

Comment: @torguestomp: I found it, I have first to set the value of the item to zero before using your code, otherwise it keeps summing on the older value. Thank you very much for your answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

it's better to use iterator

```
    int n = 1;
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 1));
    ListIterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator();
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (it.next().equals(n)) {
            indexes.add(it.nextIndex() - 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(indexes);
```

Comment: Seems to me that OP actually wants a single number as output (assuming he/she can't figure out that he/she can change the push to `List` to perform part of the calculation instead).

Comment: Yes, I think this will work. I will integrate it to my code and I will give you a feedback. Thank you.

Comment: Dont do it. Now I understnad that you dont need indexes, better take torquestomp's answer