# Code doesn't works but I get no error messages

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, illegalargumentexception

**Error:** Strange enough I get no errors.

**What I'm trying to make:** ( I also added // messages that explains what my code does.)

What I'm trying to make is fairly simple.

1) Fill in a name in the JTextField, press enter and the name should appear in the JTextArea. After the name is in the JTextArea the JTextField becomes empty so you can fill another name and so on there should appear a list of names in JTextArea.

**2) Push the button kiesWin to make the program choose a random person from the list. (here it goes wrong)**

3) Push the button resetL to reset the program so I can make a new list to choose a random winner from it.

**Problem:** When I Push the button Kies (Translated: Choose) it should choose a random name from the ArrayList and show the random name in the JTextField textvak2. But when I push the button Kies the program does nothing. And it should show me the random chosen name from the ArrayList.

**This is the class that doesn't works properly:** (I Think)

```
// This is the button that chooses a random name from the ArrayList.
// The random chosen name should appear in the JTextField textvak2. (but it doesn't)
// This is also the part where it goes wrong at the moment.
class Kies extends OnthoudNaam implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        Random r = new Random();
        if (lijst.size() > 0) {
            int n = r.nextInt(lijst.size());
            Naam kiesNaam = lijst.get(n);
            textvak2.setText(kiesNaam.getIngevoerdNaam());
            }
    }
}
```

**For in case you need the whole code:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

// Main method to make the frame.
public class Loterij3 extends JFrame {
public static void main( String args[] ) {
    JFrame frame = new Loterij3();
    frame.setExtendedState( frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setTitle( "My Lottery!" );
    frame.setContentPane( new Paneel() );
    frame.setVisible( true );
}
}

// This is the Panel that goes into the frame.
class Paneel extends JPanel {
private Boven boven;
JTextArea textvak1;
JTextField textvak2;
OnthoudNaam onthoudNaam = new OnthoudNaam();
JTextField invoervak1; // JTextField from class Boven.

public Paneel() {
setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); // using border Layout.
setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );

boven = new Boven(); 

textvak1 = new JTextArea();
add( new JScrollPane( textvak1 ) );
textvak1.setBackground( Color.WHITE );

textvak2 = new JTextField();
textvak2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER); 

add( boven, BorderLayout.NORTH ); // Where the class Boven should be.
add( textvak1, BorderLayout.CENTER );
add( textvak2, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
}

// This is the class Boven (Translation up or upper).
// This is where the JButtons, JTextField and JLabels are.
public class Boven extends JPanel {
JButton kiesWin, resetL;
JLabel label1;

public Boven() {
    setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
    setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, 4, 100, 5 ) ); // using GridLayout.
    Border border = 
        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder( 10, 10, 10, 10 );
    setBorder( border );

    kiesWin = new JButton("Kies een Winnaar!");
    kiesWin.addActionListener( new Kies() );
    resetL = new JButton("Reset alles");
    resetL.addActionListener( new Reset() );
    label1 = new JLabel("Voer Persoon in en druk op enter: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
    invoervak1 = new JTextField( 20 );
    invoervak1.addActionListener( new InvoerVakHandler() );

    add( label1 );
    add( invoervak1 );
    add( kiesWin );
    add( resetL );
    }
}

// The class Naam (translation = name).
// This is what the ArrayList should remember
// In other words ArrayList should remember the Names I put in the JTextField.
class Naam {
    private String ingevoerdNaam;

    public Naam( String ingevoerdNaam) {
        this.ingevoerdNaam = ingevoerdNaam;
    }

    public String getIngevoerdNaam() {
        return ingevoerdNaam;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ingevoerdNaam;
    }
}

// This is my ArrayList,
// This should remember the names I type in the JTextField.
class OnthoudNaam extends JPanel {
    protected ArrayList<Naam> lijst;

    public OnthoudNaam() {
        lijst = new ArrayList<Naam>();
        }

        public void voegNaamToe(Naam x ) {
        lijst.add(x);
        }

        public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(Naam x : lijst ) {
        buffer.append( x );
        buffer.append( "\n" );
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
}

// This is the JTextField where I enter the names.
// The Name I fill in the JTextField should be remembered by the ArrayList.
// The Name I fill in should be put in the JTextArea.
public class InvoerVakHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        String invoer = invoervak1.getText();
        Naam Naam = new Naam( invoer );
        onthoudNaam.voegNaamToe( Naam );
        textvak1.setText( onthoudNaam.toString() );
        invoervak1.setText( "" );
    }
}
    // This is the button that chooses a random name from the ArrayList.
    // This is also the part where it goes wrong at the moment.
class Kies extends OnthoudNaam implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        Random r = new Random();
        if (lijst.size() > 0) {
            int n = r.nextInt(lijst.size());
            Naam kiesNaam = lijst.get(n);
            textvak2.setText(kiesNaam.getIngevoerdNaam());
            }
    }
}

// This should become the button that resets everything so you can start over.
class Reset implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072594/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-n-must-be-positiv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Random#nextInt` requires a positive number but the initial size of the `List` `lijst` is `0` hence the Exception

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) clearly state this

> **Throws:**
>   IllegalArgumentException - if n is not positive

Check that there are entries in the `List` first.

```
if (lijst.size() > 0) {
   int n = r.nextInt(lijst.size());
   Naam kiesNaam = lijst.get(n);
   textvak2.setText(kiesNaam.getIngevoerdNaam());
}
```

Aside: Rather than casting the object from the `List`, extract the `Naam` object and use its `getIngevoerdNaam` method.

Remember too *The debugger is your friend*

Comment: Now i get no errors when compiling, executing or when pressing the button. But when I push the button it still does not shows who is the random chosen name from the ArrayList. (I changed the code in the main post above)

Comment: JTextField textvak2 still remains empty

Comment: So can you please answer this question in here? then I accept the answer

Comment: every time I post a question I get an answer but then I get a new error. So I have to post again, and then again and again.

Comment: You will have many issues as you develop. Learn to use the debugger. This make it easier to track down these issues.

Comment: If this is a problem what if I change the whole post and title to this new problem. Will it be ok then?

Comment: I'm trying to make this program for the last 3 days now. I've been solving errors for 12 hours each day now. I would appreciate it verry much if you could give me an answer so it will work :/

Comment: or atleast give me a hint where the problem lies couse I'm clueless and I can't post again