# unable to produce random number?

Tags: java

Each object in my warehouseList contains a end stock, safety stock, and a required stock. 
My aim to change the end stock of an object if lesser that 10% of the safety stock, and put it in range of -%10 to %5 of the safety stock. To do this im using a randomizer code:

```
Random random=new Random();
for(Warehouse obj:warehouseList){

    double diff=obj.getEndStock()-obj.getSafetyStock();

    if(((diff/obj.getSafetyStock())*100)<(-5)){
        diff=Math.abs(diff)+(1.05*obj.getSafetyStock())-obj.getSafetyStock();
        if(diff<0)
            Logging.log(diff,"\n");
        int randomNum=0;
        double reqStock=0;
        double end=obj.getEndStock();

        while(((end-obj.getSafetyStock())*100)<(-5)){

            randomNum=random.nextInt((int)diff);
            reqStock+=randomNum;
            end+=randomNum;
        }
        obj.setRequiredStock(reqStock);
        obj.setEndStock(end);


    }
}
```

}

Now to the problem: I'm checking if the diff variable even becomes negative as it doesnt as nothing prints on the console, However whenever i reach the the line *randomNum=random.nextInt((int)diff);*
the program throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at managing.Final.randomWay(Final.java:163)
    at managing.Final.main(Final.java:252)
```

CAN ANYONE HELP?

Comment: you should call `random.nextInt()` with positive argument

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072594/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-n-must-be-positiv)

Comment: Try changing your log check to `if((int)diff <=0)`

Answer (score 3):

This is rather simple.  Look at these two lines:

```
double diff=obj.getEndStock()-obj.getSafetyStock();
...
randomNum=random.nextInt((int)diff);
```

Your `diff` contains a difference between *end stock* and *safety stock*.  If your *end stock* is below *safety stock*, then `diff` will contain a negative number.

`nextInt` method requires a positive integer as a parameter.  If your `diff` is negative, you'll get this error.

**EDIT:** In response to the comment I re-read the question carefully again and noticed the line I missed.  With this line:

```
diff=Math.abs(diff)+(1.05*obj.getSafetyStock())-obj.getSafetyStock();
```

You actually can get a `0`. (I am assuming that your `getSafetyStock` would always return a positive number - if it doesn't, then this may be your problem.)

In your code, you are checking whether `diff` is `0` - but are not doing anything about it, other than printing a log line.

On the whole, it may make sense to print the value of `diff` regardless of what it is before using it as a parameter for `nextInt` - for debugging purposes.

Comment: diff=Math.abs(diff)+(1.05*obj.getSafetyStock())-obj.getSafetyStock();
this takes care of that

Comment: @user3540384 Yes, sorry, missed that line.  I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks alot that worked :), just one more thing, for some reason the in some alot of cases the end stock value has a value 5% more than the safety stock, I'm I doing something wrong in the while loop

Answer (score 0):

I see no check for negative value. Here:

```
 if(diff==0)
            Logging.log(diff,"\n");
```

You check for zero-equality, which is weird for double-typed variable anyway.

Comment: ohhh damn, but I did check for negative also, it still didnt print anything

Comment: @user3540384 Most likely, because `double diff = 0; System.out.print(diff)` would produce something like _0.00000000000099999_.

Comment: Do declare a separate integer variable, assign rounded diff to it and print it to the log right before generating a random value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I get what's wrong. nextInt method **requires** it's argument to be **positive**, but you are **checking** if it is **non-negative**. That's what causes the error.

This code prooves my point:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        System.out.println(random.nextInt(0));
    }
}
```

it generates an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:300)
    at RandomMain.main(RandomMain.java:6)
```